# Inspect LocalStorage of other sites using Chrome / Firefox devtools

Tags: local-storage, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Are there any possible ways we can use devtools of Chrome / Firefox to inspect `LocalStorage` object of site `http://example.com`, when we are currently on `http://example2.com` ? Seems like they only allow to inspect on same site for now.

The story is, I'm working on an authentication function which involves lots of redirecting, and I need to check if the page is redirected, is the `LocalStorage` data correct or not.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is a way to block redirecting to be able to inspect the local storage data of the redirecting sites.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've asked in the [Firefox discussion forum](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/block-network-redirects/72947) now for a way to block redirects within the DevTools.

Comment: Yes I believe some redirect blocking mechanism would also help in this case. For now it looks like something out of reach, so I need to block the redirect manually and check the underlying storage data. Btw, thanks for creating the discussion  :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chrome as well as the Firefox DevTools currently (as of Chrome 87 and Firefox 84) only allow to inspect the local and session storage data of the current page context.

Also, as far as I know, there is no other integrated option to inspect all the data saved for a specific domain or URL without navigating to it first.

So the proper way to inspect such data is to avoid those redirects from happening. Though there's no tool I'm aware of that can stop all redirects. That's why I've [asked for it in Mozilla's discussion forum](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/block-network-redirects/72947).

None the less, in Firefox, there's one (admittedly quite complicated) way to inspect the data saved for a specific domain. Firefox saves all local storage data in an SQLite database. This database can be read by any tool that allows to open SQLite files. (There are even browser add-ons allowing to read them.) Here are the steps how to access the data:

1. Go to `about:support`
2. Click the "Open Folder" button besides the "Profile Folder" label
   => Opens the folder of your current Firefox profile in the operating system's navigator.
3. In the folder, search for the file webappsstore.sqlite
4. Open the file in an SQLite managing tool.
5. Execute the following query to see the data related to the domain http://example.com

   ```sql
   SELECT key, value FROM webappsstore2 WHERE originKey = 'moc.elpmaxe.:http:80'
   ```

   You may already see it but the domain name saved in the `originKey` column is the other way round. I don't know why. So the format is `<domain name with dot at the beginning the other way round>:<protocol>:<port>`.